# Second fragment loaded but not visible on screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm adding 2 fragments to the Activity. After startup I see only title bar but no main UI. Here is code of activity and layout. If I comment out title fragment - main UI shows up. I'm sure it's something simple but can't figure out what to change to make them both appear

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_activity_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!--<fragment android:name="com.idatt.activities.TitleBarFragment"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/fr_title_bar"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"/>-->
        <fragment android:name="com.idatt.activities.LoginFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fr_login"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/login_activity_drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to `wrap_content` for `layout_height` of both fragments. Try this:

```
<LinearLayout  android:orientation="vertical"     
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <fragment android:name="com.idatt.activities.TitleBarFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fr_title_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <fragment android:name="com.idatt.activities.LoginFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fr_login"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the parent view(being LinearLayout) has a wrapcontent attribute and the child(being each fragment) has a match parent attribute then you have 2 views pulling in opposite directions - On the one hand you got the LinearLayout trying to shrink itself to the size of its contents and on the other its contents are trying(both) to stretch to the size of their father.
The other problem is: because both of the fragments height match their parents(with this being a vertical  linear layout), you got both fragments entirely covering the linear layout so one fragment is not leaving any space for another.

Thus what you need to do is take each fragment's height attribute and set it to "wrapcontent" which will effectively solve both problems.
By not matching their parent's size the first fragment will leave space for the second fragment to be visible and because the linear layout wraps its content he'll be just the right size for both fragments to fit entirely and exactly.